# Do non-metal objects reduce the signal strength of a computer wireless network device?

Tags: waves

Would an object like a wooden bed interfere or block the signal coming from a 802.11 wireless router?

Comment: I don't know why I was voted down, is this not a question about the how our physical reality works?

Comment: My guess would be because of the unclear classification of this site itself; it handles Research questions and introductory questions; probably not an ideal situation.

Comment: Yeah, thats a good point, I hadn't fully considered that. Although how does one become an expert without starting from many introductory questions?

Comment: I think you misread Noon's comment. It handles both research AND introductory questions. I think your question was regarded as too plain, though I wouldn't vote it down.

Answer (score 4):

The question is about physics, but not in terms easily answerable by a physicist.

- What is the bed made of (spring mattresses have lots of metal inside)?
- At what frequency is the source of EM waves?
- Where are you measuring the waves w.r.t. the bed and router?

etc.

---

In general, yes there will be some dampening, depending on the factors above.

Comment: But don't you see it was answerable: "yes there will be some dampening, depending on the factors above." This is one such answer.  It's an easy question.

Comment: I didn't vote you down. The question should be improved though :-)

Answer (score 2):

WiFi signals are just microwaves, so they are affected by the same things. If something would prevent a microwave oven from working, there is a good chance it will also block a wireless signal.

In case of a wooden bed, humidity in the wood could reduce the signal, although not by much. Even if wood would absorb microwaves, a bed is typically not a massive slab of it, but has openings between the slats etc.. You would more likely get an effect from any springs in the matress. Other things that commonly weaken the signal are steel in reenforced concrete walls, and anti-glare coatings on windows.

This would be a great case for an experiment btw..